# Jasper Report Takes too long to load for first time in Java Application

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I use jasper reports to generate invoices and GRNs in my java application, I use following class to fill up the data

```
public class IReport extends JFrame {

    public IReport(String filename,HashMap parameter){

        super("View Report");
        try {
             DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
            JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.xpath.executer.factory",
    "net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.xml.JaxenXPathExecuterFactory");
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(filename, parameter, DatabaseService.getConnection());

            JRViewer viewer = new JRViewer(print);

            Container c = getContentPane();
            c.add(viewer);


        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        toFront();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

and I use following method to call the report by parsing necessary parameters through a button click.

```
private void printReport(String grnno) {
        HashMap param = new HashMap();
        param.put("grnno", grnno);
        param.put("header1", dilukz_inventory.DILUKZ_INVENTORY.owner.getHeader1());
        param.put("header2", dilukz_inventory.DILUKZ_INVENTORY.owner.getHeader2());
        param.put("address", dilukz_inventory.DILUKZ_INVENTORY.owner.getAddress());
        param.put("telephone", dilukz_inventory.DILUKZ_INVENTORY.owner.getContactno());

        IReport showme = new IReport("Reports/GRN.jasper", param);       
        showme.setVisible(true);

    }
```

But the problem is when I do it for the first time after I opened the application it takes too long to load the report, like it takes up to 20 - 30 seconds. What can I do to avoid that? please suggest me away.